# Filter a hierarchical list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Here is my model for Product

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public int ProductNumber{ get; set; }

    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
}

//// below is the structure of the list
IList<Product> rootList = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product 
                { 
                    ProductNumber = 1, Name = "A", 
                    ProductList = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductNumber = 2, Name = "A1", 
                        ProductList = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductNumber = 3, Name = "A2", ProductList = new List<Product>()} }}  
                    }
                },

                new Product 
                { 
                    ProductNumber = 4, Name = "B", 
                    ProductList = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductNumber = 5, Name = "B1", 
                        ProductList = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductNumber = 6, Name = "B2", ProductList = new List<Product>()} }}  
                    }
                },

                 new Product 
                { 
                    ProductNumber = 7, Name = "C", 
                    ProductList = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductNumber = 8, Name = "C1", 
                        ProductList = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductNumber = 9, Name = "C2", ProductList = new List<Product>()} }}  
                    }
                }
            };
```

I need to filter the above list which contain the ProductNumber less than 5, ie. the output is expected to be a list of Product which has product numbers less than 5.

is there any extensions available? Please help.

Here my expected result

```
            Product 
            { 
                ProductNumber : 1, 
                Name : "A", 
                ProductList : { { 
                          ProductNumber : 2, 
                          Name : "A1", 
                          ProductList :{ { 
                                  ProductNumber = 3, 
                                  Name : "A2", 
                                  ProductList : null} }}  
                }
            },

            Product 
            { 
                ProductNumber : 4, 
                Name : "B"
                ProductList : null
            }
```

Comment: Are you talkign about filtering things where any of the inner productlists have products with numbers less than five? Or maybe that all the inner lists need to be filtered to have products removed too? I'm a little confused... Maybe if you put what you want returned it might make it clearer for us... I'm assuming its not just the product in your rootlist having productnumber < 5 since that is plain simple linq...

Comment: I have updated my expected result structure. Can you please look

Comment: I've written some code to let you get the results you want provided you are happy to modify your original tree. If not, you will want to look into _deep cloning_ your tree, then run the code on the clone.

Comment: -1, you asked for one specific feature and output, but then accepted a totally different one, you should at least consider adapting your question to the accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly easy to knock together a "flatten-this-tree" LINQ-like function

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    HashSet<T> added = new HashSet<T>();
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    foreach(T t in source)
        if (added.Add(t))
            queue.Enqueue(t);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        T current = queue.Dequeue();
        yield return current;
        if (current != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> children = childSelector(current);
            if (children != null)
                foreach(T t in childSelector(current))
                    if (added.Add(t))
                        queue.Enqueue(t);
        }
    }
}
```

which you can then use in regular LINQ e.g.

```
var lessThanFive = rootList
    .Flatten(p => p.ProductList)
    .Where(p => p.ProductNumber < 5)
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT**: From your edit I can see that this isn't quite what you wanted. (You don't want a list of products, you want a tree of products...) I'm going to leave this here as I quite like it as a solution to what I *thought* your problem was, but I'll have a think about your new problem too...

**EDIT**: If you don't mind modifying your original objects, you can use this as follows:

```
rootList = rootList.Where(p => p.ProductNumber < 5).ToList();
foreach (var pr in rootList.Flatten(p => p.ProductList))
    pr.ProductList = pr.ProductList.Where(p => p.ProductNumber < 5).ToList();
```

Comment: I've done this often enough for specific cases, I'm amazed I haven't put together a generic method like this before now.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TR> Recur<T, TR>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, 
        Func<T, bool> filter, 
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> recursor, 
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>, TR> resultor)
    {
        foreach(var t in source)
            if (filter(t))
                yield return resultor(t, recursor(t));
    }
}
```

which you'll call like this:

```
var q = rootList.Recur(
    p => p.ProductNumber < 5,
    p => p.ProductList,
    (p, cs) => new 
    {
        p.ProductNumber, 
        p.Name,
        ProductList = cs 
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but this solutions is not working for higher page number say 8

Comment: Could you elaborate please? The method takes one predicate and yields elements satisfying it, as per your request, number 8 for not satisfy it and gets excluded, as in your sample.